# Facebook apprequest messages are not displayed on receiver's notifications list

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to send a direct message to friends using Facebook Dialogs on Android. The code that does is as follows:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "sending direct messages");
    params.putString("to", friendId);
    mFacebook.dialog(FBFriendsActivity.this, "apprequests", params, new PostDialogListener());
```

The code executes well. No error. The Facebook send dialog shows up, and I click on send. but, I do not see any notifications listed on the receiver's notifications.

Do I have to have a facebook app in order for this to work? If so, how do I send user-to-user requests?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume one of three things.

1. You application is still in test mode
2. The app request went to a test user rather than a normal user account
3. Most importantly, your app may not be properly configured as a **canvas app**.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ for more information

Comment: Thanks for the response.
1. Yes, I am still building my app.
2. I am using regular Facebook user accounts. Not test account.
3. It is not a "canvas app". My App is an Android App and can interface with Facebook.
What I am trying to achieve is simple. I want to send a private message to my friend like "Do you want to be on my Baseball team?" and I do not want any of my friends or his friends to see it.

Comment: There's your answer then.  You app is not configured as a canvas app.  You **MUST** have it configured as a canvas app for the apprequests to work.

Comment: I've figured out so far that we do not canvas app. However, the registered app should have the sso enabled.

Comment: So are you saying Facebook's documentation is incorrect about to send app requests, your app must be configured as a canvas app?  If so, then you should file a documentation bug with Facebook to have this corrected.

Comment: @DMCS: I am facing the same thing. see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282127/not-able-to-see-app-request-post-from-the-default-facebook-app-or-browser

Comment: @DMCS: is this because of i haven't configured it as canvas app ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Per Facebook's documentation as of Jun 12th, 2012, it MUST be a canvas app for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "direct message"? inbox message? I don't think Facebook Android API supports this...

yes, you need a Facebook app, otherwise how do you instantiate `mFacebook`? Suppose it is `Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");`. But I think you do have your Facebook app, because you said a dialog had shown and you had clicked the send.

for your code, that is what you would do if you want to send app requests to your friends.

you may want to take a look at this tutorial which shows you the key steps for the Facebook integration.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register

Comment: Thanks Candy for the response. I've gone through the steps mentioned in the link you've given. At the stage when I am displaying the RequestDialog, user has already authorized and given the access_token to my app. As I mentioned, clicking on send button does not report any error. Question is where the message would show up on my friends page after I click on the "Send" button? I do not see it in my friend's Inbox or Notifications.

Comment: no, not in inbox, since you're sending app request, your friend should receive a notification saying "xxx has sent you a request in YourApp". if your friend clicks "Apps and Games" on the left menu bar, he will see a list of app requests. then it depends on whether he has installed your Facebook app; if no, he won't see the message, just a "xxx invited you to try YourApp! Try Now"; if yes, then he should see your message, and buttons for accept and decline.

Comment: thanks. I need to have a Facebook App for apprequest to work. That explains why my messages are not showing up.<br/>
Looks like I am on a wrong path here. What I want to do is to send a personal message to my friend. I know I can write on his wall. But that is not personal as it is visible to others. Is there a way to send a message to his inbox or notification through the APIs?